# Dynamic event building in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd like to create an event for each function in a script, then inject the event trigger into the end of the function.

This way I can see exactly when each function has completed and use the events like hooks for other functions

If I can do it dynamically, I can add as many new functions as I like without having to create and append these events.

Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do, this won't actually work, but it gives you an idea. I have been using jQuery, but I'll accept any JavaScript framework at all, and any method.

```
var obj = {};

(function()
{
    this.init = function()
    {
        // loop through every function
        $.each(this, function(k, v)
        {
            // create an event for every function
            $('body').bind(v, function()
            {
                 console.log('Event: ' + v + ' Finished');
            });

            // Add a event trigger into each specific function in the loop
            this[v].call($('body').trigger(v));
        });
    }
    
    this.another_function = function()
    {
        // do something
    }

    this.some_function = function()
    {
         /do something
    }

}).apply(obj);

obj.init();
```

(edit) The script itself basically renders a Calendar, but there are a lot of callbacks, ajax requests, buttons. etc... If I could tie each feature down to an event, it would make my life easier when extending it, adding new features etc...

Comment: can you give more details on what you have as an input, with some examples of your functions/handlers ?

Comment: I added a few more details in my edit, but theres not much more than that. Its just an idea I had that might work for me if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through every function, replace it with new one, which calls original function on the same object and triggers event on body.

```
var obj = { };

(function()
{
    this.init = function()
    {
        var self = this;
        foreach(var name in this) {
            if (typeof k !== 'Function') continue;
            if (name ==='init') continue;

            var original = this[name];

            var newFunc = function() {
                original.apply(self, arguments);
                $('body').trigger(name);
            }

            this[name] = newFunc;
        } 
    }

this.another_function = function()
    {
        // do something
    }

this.some_function = function()
    {
         /do something
    }

}).apply(obj);

obj.init();
```

Comment: Yes, I see where your coming from here, but I wanted to not only invoke the events dynamically, but trigger each event automatically when each function completed its task.

Comment: Oh it seems i get what you want to achive here. see changes